# How do I make sure my getUserProfile cloud function in firebase only returns data if the logged in user's session requests it?

Tags: node.js, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

I have a cloud function called `getUserProfile` that looks like this:

```
exports.getUserProfile = functions.https.onRequest((request, res) => {
    try {
        const username = request.body.username || request.query.username;
        if (username == null || username.length == 0) return res.send('{"status":"error","errorMessage":"No username Provided."}');

        admin.database().ref().child("users").orderByChild("username").equalTo(username).once('value', snapshot => {
            if (!snapshot.exists()) return res.send(`{"status":"error","message":"invalid-profile"}`);
            
            snapshot.forEach(function(child) {
                const id = child.val().id;
                admin.database().ref('users/' + id).once('value', snapshot => {
                    if (!snapshot.exists()) return res.send('{"status":"error","errorMessage":"user not found."}');

                    let userData = {}
                    userData.username = snapshot.val().username || "N/A";
                    userData.name = snapshot.val().name || "N/A";
                    userData.email = snapshot.val().email || "N/A";

                    admin.database().ref('uploads').orderByChild('createdBy').equalTo(id).once('value', snapshot => {
                        userData.content = {};
                        const filePromise = [];
                        snapshot.forEach(function(child) {
                            let content = {};
                            content.id = child.key;
                            content.val = child.val();
                            content.val.files.forEach(function(fileId) {
                                filePromise.push(admin.database().ref().child("files").child(fileId.fileId).once("value"));
                            });

                            userData.content[child.key] = content;
                            userData.content[child.key].files = [];
                        });
                        Promise.all(filePromise).then(results => {
                            results.forEach((result => {
                                const uploadId = result.val().uploadId;
                                const thumbDownloadURL = result.val().thumbDownloadURL;
                                userData.content[uploadId].files.push(thumbDownloadURL);
                            }));
                            res.send(`{"status":"ok","userdata":${JSON.stringify(userData)}}`);
                        });
                    });

                });
            });

        });
    } catch (err) {
        res.send(`{"status":"error","message":"${err}"}`);
    }
});
```

I use this function to get the user profile's details and render them on the view. However, if someone makes a request let's say from https://reqbin.com/ along with sending {"username": "xxx"} JSON content, the function is still returning the data which is a security breach, and this is an expected behavior. How do I make sure that only the logged-in user gets the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use JWT authentication to verify users who want to request data from your firebase cloud function. So when a user first signs up a Token is assigned to that user (which can be renewed or revoked when needed), then whenever that user wants to request data they need to send their token by adding Authentication: Bearer + UserJWToken to the request header. Then on the cloud function's side you can verify that token and

here are some links that could help with the subject:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens

https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens

https://itnext.io/firebase-cloud-functions-verify-users-tokens-d4e60e314d1a